# How we can run automated test cases using katalon studio in mobile(Android/IOS),since i am new to this tool seeking for configuration as well

Tags: android, ios, mobile, katalon-studio

How we can run automated test cases using katalon studio in mobile with Android and IOS platform.

Since i am new to this tool seeking for configuration of this tool for mobile testing

Answer (score 1):

Have you read the documentation?
https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/Mobile+on+Windows

Also always start with recording a TestCase and add on it later
https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/Recording+Mobile+Test